# Getting incremental changes from Neo4j DB

Tags: neo4j

Is there any way in Neo4j 1.9, to get all the nodes/relationships that were modified(created/updated/deleted) within certain span of time - like we do in SOLR delta import?

One crude way I can think of is maintain a timestamp property for each node/relationship and index them to fetch those nodes/relationship.

```
START a=node:custom_index("timestamp:[{start_time} TO {end_time}]")
RETURN a;
```

But then the question would be if I modify the node via CYPHER, index will not be updated.

Answer (score 2):

There's no built-in functionality like that in Neo4j, unfortunately.

To address issues one by one. Maintaining timestamp is not possible, because you have nowhere to put it in the case of deleted nodes/relationships. You can't put a timestamp on a property either. So you would know a node has been changed, but wouldn't know how.

One possible solution is to log the changes somewhere as they happen, using TransactionEventHandlers. Then, you can a) choose exactly what to record, and b) don't worry about Cypher, it will be logged no matter what method you used to update the database.

I've put together a [small demo](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-framework/blob/123063bd5a99d189f80e6befcbf9010e55064890/tx-api/src/test/java/com/graphaware/tx/event/demo/ChangeLoggingDemo.java). It just logs every change to std out. It uses some [GraphAware](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-framework#improved-transaction-event-api) classes (disclaimer: I'm the author) for simplicity, but could be written without them, if you feel so inclined.

Here's the important part of the code, in case the link gets eventually broken or something:

```
@Test
public void demonstrateLoggingEveryChange() {
    GraphDatabaseService database = new TestGraphDatabaseFactory().newImpermanentDatabase();

    database.registerTransactionEventHandler(new ChangeLogger());

    //perform mutations here
}

private class ChangeLogger extends TransactionEventHandler.Adapter<Void> {

    @Override
    public void afterCommit(TransactionData data, Void state) {
        ImprovedTransactionData improvedData = new LazyTransactionData(data);

        for (Node createdNode : improvedData.getAllCreatedNodes()) {
            System.out.println("Created node " + createdNode.getId()
                    + " with properties: " + new SerializablePropertiesImpl(createdNode).toString());
        }

        for (Node deletedNode : improvedData.getAllDeletedNodes()) {
            System.out.println("Deleted node " + deletedNode.getId()
                    + " with properties: " + new SerializablePropertiesImpl(deletedNode).toString());
        }

        for (Change<Node> changedNode : improvedData.getAllChangedNodes()) {
            System.out.println("Changed node " + changedNode.getCurrent().getId()
                    + " from properties: " + new SerializablePropertiesImpl(changedNode.getPrevious()).toString()
                    + " to properties: " + new SerializablePropertiesImpl(changedNode.getCurrent()).toString());
        }

        for (Relationship createdRelationship : improvedData.getAllCreatedRelationships()) {
            System.out.println("Created relationship " + createdRelationship.getId()
                    + " between nodes " + createdRelationship.getStartNode().getId()
                    + " and " + createdRelationship.getEndNode().getId()
                    + " with properties: " + new SerializablePropertiesImpl(createdRelationship).toString());
        }

        for (Relationship deletedRelationship : improvedData.getAllDeletedRelationships()) {
            System.out.println("Deleted relationship " + deletedRelationship.getId()
                    + " between nodes " + deletedRelationship.getStartNode().getId()
                    + " and " + deletedRelationship.getEndNode().getId()
                    + " with properties: " + new SerializablePropertiesImpl(deletedRelationship).toString());
        }

        for (Change<Relationship> changedRelationship : improvedData.getAllChangedRelationships()) {
            System.out.println("Changed relationship " + changedRelationship.getCurrent().getId()
                    + " between nodes " + changedRelationship.getCurrent().getStartNode().getId()
                    + " and " + changedRelationship.getCurrent().getEndNode().getId()
                    + " from properties: " + new SerializablePropertiesImpl(changedRelationship.getPrevious()).toString()
                    + " to properties: " + new SerializablePropertiesImpl(changedRelationship.getCurrent()).toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Michal, but with this I need to maintain another system wherein all this changes will go and will be querying from in there. What I am looking for is, get me all nodeIds that have changed, so that I can process them.

Comment: Careful with node IDs, they are recycled. So when you delete a node, its ID will eventually be assigned to a different node. You should use your own identifiers. As for maintaining a different system, well, that's an option. Other options include posting the changes to a message queue, or to a text file, or storing them somewhere in the graph (careful with that, if it's in one place, then it will be a hotspot for locks)...

Comment: You could have a linked list of nodes, i.e. an event list managed by the transaction event handler. @MichalBachman about contention, only one thread can commit at any given time anyway so if only the handler writes to that queue than it will not be a bottleneck for something else.

Comment: Hi Mattias, regarding the contention, I was talking about a scenario where you, for example, link every changed node to the root node with a HAS_CHANGED relationship. In that case, every tx would try to lock the root node, resulting in decreased throughput in multi-threaded environments. Is that correct? Thanks.

Comment: Regarding your solution, that would definitely be an option, but it wouldn't survive restarts I guess.